Rails k8s app only some logs are going to the pod logs / stdout
I have a rails app deployed to a k8s cluster.
The rails app is configured to send logs to stdout:
  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

If a shell in to the container I can verify the RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true is present.
When I look at the pod logs:
kubectl logs mypod

I do see some logs in there like:

=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.1.3.3 application starting in production

And I see some logging from Sidekiq:

I, [2024-12-28T00:58:47.892420 #1]  INFO -- :
[4fb530f6-fc26-4931-a868-4b6aaf90f04c] Started GET
"/sidekiq/recurring-jobs" for 10.42.0.0 at 2024-12-28 00:58:47 +0000

But as I use the app I see nothing from the apps logs.
I've put test Rails.logger.fatal("test") type statements in the app, and I've done that via the rails console on the pod but still nothing.
I also tried to just write to stdout and see if that makes the logs but it doesn't:
echo "Test to STDOUT" > /dev/stdout

I'm not sure why sidekiq and puma are logging but nothing from the main application.
Update
I found this article:
https://blog.eq8.eu/til/ruby-logs-and-puts-not-shown-in-docker-container-logs.html
He has this as a test from the console:
require 'logger'
Logger.new('/proc/1/fd/1').warn('hi')

This does go to the container logs.
This post was from 2018 though. He has a solution for the production.rb file, but this feels like a hack. There must be something else going on here.
